# xcode4 svn commit failed: File .xcodeproj/project.pbxproj is out of date

Tags: svn, xcode4, commit

Just getting started in xcode 4 and svn, opened my project (had been using xcode3 and svn) but now when I commit I have no trouble except when I try to commigt the file project.pbxproj and I get the message about being out of date.   Probably an easy problem but I'm such a newb with macs, xcode and svn I'm stuck.

Also is there a really good tutorial on using svn with xcode, I've been trying to use the one at apple but it was pretty useless,  when I do a  checkout i get not just a working copy but it seems to copy over the whole svn repository beside my working copy. I know there are a bunch of tuts found via google but I'm asking if you can recommend a really good one.  I might need to even redesign my repository since some of my previous commits(before i upgraded to xcode4) seem to have been ignored.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you are trying to commit is out of date, meaning it has been changed in the repository since you last updated.

Execute this and resolve any conflicts (if any):

```
svn up project.pbxproj
```

Then you can commit again.

Answer (score 0):

When you see this message, run SVN's Update command. I don't know about XCode 4, but in XCode 3 there are "Update Entire Project" and "Update To" SCM menu commands.

If update ends in conflicts, read generic SVN tutorial about what they are and what to do.